# SQL JOIN on Temporary Table Reducing Rowcount

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table (raw) set up in Amazon Redshift, indexed on a unique ID (VID) and timestamp (timestamp) for each unique data point. Each type of data also has a mode (mode), value (val), and data point id (PID) associated with it.

```
Timestamp, VID,  PID, VAL, MODE
0001,      V001, P01,   0, DRIVE
0002,      V001, P02,   1, DRIVE
```

I created a temporary table (_tmp) that has 'start' and 'end' periods for certain events in the data.

```
MODE, Start,  End, Duration, VID
DRIVE, 0001, 0002,       1,  V001
```

The temporary table's existence is not related to my question. My concern is also NOT about query time, but instead about rowcounts.

The temporary table has 150 rows in it. I am attempting to get the number of unique timestamps in the original data for a certain PID, where it's value is 0 - within each "start" and "end" of each row of the temporary table.

Essentially -

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT "r"."timestamp"), "t"."start"
FROM _tmp t
JOIN raw r ON "r"."timestamp" between "t"."start" and "t"."end"
WHERE "r"."pid" = 'P01' AND "r"."VAL" = 0
GROUP BY "t"."start"
```

The problem I am facing is that, due to (I assume) missing data in the 'raw' table, I am getting a rowcount of ~50 instead of the 150 I need from the _tmp table. Null values are fine, but lessened rows are not. I've tried different types of joins - the issue seems to be that the 'PID' I'm looking for doesn't exist in certain timeranges of the original data.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely correct that the "where" clause is not helping. I think you need (a) a LEFT join to retain all the records in _tmp prior to the filter, and a modified WHERE clause to include the non-matches (which will provide NULL values from those fields).

`count()` only counts non-null values so it should be fine.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT "r"."timestamp"), "t"."start"
FROM _tmp t
LEFT JOIN raw r ON "r"."timestamp" between "t"."start" and "t"."end"
WHERE ( "r"."pid" = 'P01' AND "r"."VAL" = 0 ) OR ("r"."pid" IS NULL AND "r"."VAL" IS NULL)
GROUP BY "t"."start"
```